# Scaffold out a job policy pattern that uses feature branches and tags in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have a task:

> Scaffold out a job policy pattern that uses feature branches and tags
> to gate review, release and staging/production job execution

but I don't really understand this question - what should be done here?

@Edit
There was an answer from @live but now it's removed for some reason.
Anyway, he wrote:

> Use GitLab's feature branching and tagging features to manage the
> different versions of your code. Whenever you start working on a new
> feature, create a new feature branch in GitLab and push your code
> changes to that branch. When the feature is complete and ready to be
> merged into the main branch, create a new tag in GitLab to mark the
> point in the code where the feature was added.
>
> Use the .gitlab-ci.yml file to define rules for when each job should
> be run. For example, you might specify that the build job should only
> be run when code is pushed to a feature branch, and the deploy job
> should only be run when a new tag is created.

Does it mean just to create a feature branch and then in `gitlab-ci.yml` file add e.g

```
only:
    - master
```

To run some stage only for e.g master or other specified branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found: https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/customer-success/professional-services-engineering/education-services/gitlabcicdhandsonlab6.html

there is example:

```
deploy review:
  stage: review
  # only: 
  #   - branches
  # except: 
  #   - master
  script:
    - echo "Do your average deploy here"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
      when: never
    - when: always
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

deploy release:
  stage: deploy
  # only:
  #   - tags
  # except: 
  #   - master
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to a production environment"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != "master" && $CI_COMMIT_TAG'
      when: manual
  environment:
    name: production

deploy staging:
  stage: deploy
  # only:
  #   - master
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to a staging environment"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"'
      when: always
    - when: never
  environment:
    name: staging
```

what was expected